# CISCO настройка OSPF для данной сети

Tags: сеть, lan, router, cisco

Как можно настроить OSPF для данной сети которая разделена на три подсети ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как вам надо?

Comment: @Smithson что б от любого роутера можно было пропинговать все роутеры.

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте по ГОСТу - три сегмента (три area), посредине area 0.
*ABR* роутеры настройте, в каждой area *OSPF* процесс, пропишите сети которые отдаются соседям.

Comment: Раз уж ссылаешься на гост, было бы хорошо указать его номер.

Comment: "Сделать по госту" тут крылатая фраза. В данном контексте значит - использовать популярные практики.